# Where may I find an IQueryable implementation of Contains for T-SQL?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Everytime I do a:

```
journals = _context.Journals
            .Where(j => j.Name.Contains("foo"));
```

I feel the need to stop and write an extension on `IQueryable` that will make the `Contains` work. Is there one available already?

Comment: Works for me. Are you `using System.Linq`?

Comment: @EricJ. I haven't compiled by bloatware yet but I say out of experience. I am surprised it works for you. Are you sure it is not running on the `IEnumerable<T>` instead? That would be very expensive.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 So you're asking how to make the code work when you haven't even tried running the code to see if it works (because it will)?  Rather than asking questions about why code that you expect to fail won't work, actually run the code, and *if* it fails, *then* consider asking about it.

Comment: I am getting the feeling that the Contains will work here because it is on the string. It wouldn't have worked if I had said something like: `_context.Journals.Where(j => someListOfT.Contains(j.Name));`.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 Try it and find out.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 Programming by "the feeling" is counter-productive.

Comment: Guys, I wrote this question while I was still typing in code in a very large code base that takes a long time to compile. I have been at it for a few days now with very little sleep, so please, just don't be rude, okay? I am not stupid.

Comment: Maybe you should take a little more time/care with your questions then? It's also rude to waste people's time with questions that you've put no effort into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework supports contains on Strings and on Local lists.

From [Docs](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/basic.html#filtering):

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Blogs
        .Where(b => b.Url.Contains("dotnet"))
        .ToList();
}
```

Also this should work:

```
List<string> urls = new List<string>() { "dotnet", "c#"};

using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Blogs
         .Where(b => urls.Contains(b.Url))
         .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Yes, my bad. I keep mixing things up and being in a hurry at times. The use case that won't work is if I ran the contains on an `IQueryable` provided by the Entity Framework, like: `_context.Foos.Where(f => _context.Bars.Contains(f.Bar));`?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 Stop asserting that things won't work until you've actually tried them and seen that they won't work.  That will also work.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 this will not work using contains, but you can use `_context.Foos.Where(f =>  _context.Bars.Any(b=> b.Bar == f.Bar))`